# Куда Postgres файлы кладёт. И как это место изменить

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Начал изучать Python 2.7 + PostgreSQL 9.6.1. На питоне уже есть небольшой опыт работы, а с PostgreSQL опыта не имею. (Windows 8)

Имеется БД `name_db`, которую создаю следующим кодом:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from psycopg2 import connect
import sys
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

con = None
con = connect(user='postgres', password='poilk', port=5432)

dbname = "name_db"

con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Вопросы:

1. Где находится "name_db"? В папке с проектом её нет. Поисковик в Windows тоже не знает таких файлов. (...PostgreSQL\9.6\data - путь к БД при установке PostgreSQL)
2. Как изменить путь сохранения файла БД в папку с проектом `.../db/`?

Answer (score 8):

В PostgreSQL  область хранения баз данных на диске принято называть *кластер баз данных*. Кластер баз данных представляет собой набор баз, управляемых одним экземпляром работающего сервера. Он должен быть проинициализирован перед первым запуском сервера.

С точки зрения файловой системы, кластер баз данных представляет собой один каталог, в котором будут храниться все данные. Где именно хранить данные, вы абсолютно свободно можете выбирать сами. Какого-либо стандартного пути не существует, но часто данные размещаются в `/usr/local/pgsql/data`.

Для инициализации кластера баз данных применяется команда `initdb`. Расположение кластера в файловой системе задаётся параметром `-D`, например:

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Настройки кластера баз данных (вместе с другими параметрами сервера) описываются в файле `postgresql.conf`.

Теперь про расположение файлов. Например, на моём Debian'е при версии PostgreSQL 9.4 кластер баз данных инициализирован в `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main`, а файл настроек расположен `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`.

Список созданных в кластере баз данных можно просмотреть, например, при помощи команды `psql`:

```
$ psql -U postgres --list
```

**P.S.** Надеюсь на людей, более сведующих, которые дополнят ответ, указав где обычно располагаются файлы PostgreSQL в Windows.

Comment: А можно для одной базы данных сделать отдельный каталог? То есть все базы данных будут храниться в одном каталоге, кроме одной, которая будет лежать в другом месте?

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать такой запрос:

```
SHOW DATA_DIRECTORY;
```

Он покажет расположение данных (в любой ОС)